# using different formats for BigDecimal in bindData

Tags: data-binding, grails, formatting

i have a class

> class Foo {
>
> BigInteger  phase
>      BigDecimal  amount
>      BigDecimal  percent
>
> }

and want to use bindData to map some user input.
The user enters data in different formats for *amount* and *percent*

i.e. :

- *amount* : 100.000,00
- *percent* : 75,50%

bindData parses this to

- *amount* = 100000 (in GERMAN Locale)
- *percent* : 75.5

is there any way to force grails to format domain-fields using different formats?  For the example i would use **NumberFormat.getNumberInstance** for *amount* and **NumberFormat.getPercentInstance** for *percent* using the current Locale....

I tried the CustomEditor thing, but this procedure is type-bound and will not work on two different formats using the same type...

Anybody any idea? ;)

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a CustomEditor should work. You just pass a custom date binder that can determine the value being submitted and transform it. In our app for example, we have a custom date binder that transforms a single date field (normally Grails expects the date split into three fields).